# Change a long code line into several short lines

Tags: r, function

In my code within a function, there are some long lines, such as this:

```
  OR <- unlist(lapply(models, function(x) broom::tidy(x, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)$estimate[2]))
  conf_low <- unlist(lapply(models, function(x) broom::tidy(x, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)$conf.low[2]))
  conf_high <- unlist(lapply(models, function(x) broom::tidy(x, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)$conf.high[2]))
```

I would like to change them into several short lines. @Paul's suggestion to define a function is a great idea but I cannot work out a way to apply one function to the above three lines. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the function, then call it in `lapply`:

```
fun <- function(x) broom::tidy(x, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)$conf.high[1])
conf_high <- unlist(lapply(models, fun)
```

### Update

I think you're looking for something like this (I made my own models):

```
library(broom)    
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(x) broom::tidy(x, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)

models <- iris %>%
  split(f = .$Species) %>%
  lapply(function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x))

lapply(models, fun) %>%
  lapply(function(x) x[2, c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high")]) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Species")

>
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    estimate conf.low conf.high
  <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa         1.99     1.66      2.39
2 versicolor     2.38     1.58      3.56
3 virginica      2.46     1.48      4.10
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I wonder if I could have one function applying to all 3 lines.

Comment: Look into the `jtools::export_summs()` function, this might also give you what you want.